# Initialize global variable in c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I declared a **Boolean global variable** in the ".h" file, and initialize it the ".cpp" file, 
I faced an error, i searched on the solution and found that i must define it as extern as following:

```
//in .h file
extern bool blindFound;

// in .cpp file
bool blindFound = false;
```

But when i print its value inside other methods, it gave me (**Null**) not false!!

Thanks,

Comment: How do you print it ?

Comment: printf(" blindFound: %s \n", blindFound );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf(" blindFound: %s \n", blindFound );
```

Is it C or C++ ? Also your compiler should have warned you. Turn the warning on and pay attention to them.

Now the error is that you are printing a boolean as a string "%s". You should print it as a integer "%d". Then false will appear as 0 and true as 1.

Comment: @alsadi90 If you are using C++ why not use the I/O methods provided by C++? `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Comment: i am working on a network simulator, ans this is the common method in it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::boolapha` is C++.

The answer Above is a little mistake.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/iostream-vs-stdio.html

Please try to avoid old `printf` from C.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/

```
// modify boolalpha flag
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::boolalpha, std::noboolalpha

int main () {
  bool b = true;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << '\n';
  std::cout << std::noboolalpha << b << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often better to wrap such variables in functions, making them local static objects. This effectively avoids order-of-initialization issues.

```
bool &blindFound()
{
  static bool blindFound = false;
  return blindFound;
}
```

Usage:

```
blindFound() = true; // set value
bool b = blindFound(); // read value
```

Have a look at the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-intrinsics.html) for more information about the so-called "static initialization order fiasco".